# What's an efficient way to store a chessboard in LISP?

Tags: clojure

What's an efficient way to store a chessboard in LISP for example to solve the 8-queens puzzle?

Comment: efficient for what? memory? access speed? lines of code?

Comment: Any answer will be different for all three languages you tagged. Pick one.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_representation_%28chess%29

Comment: efficient for checking if one piece threatens another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the 8 queens problem, your *most efficient storage* is going to be an array of 8 bytes. Clojure provides the [`byte-array`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/byte-array) method to simplify the process of creating just such an array. Treat each byte as an array of 8 bits, and use 0 for an empty square and 1 for a queen.

This will not work if you intend to use more than one type of Chess piece; additionally, you should consider a different approach if you want variable board sizes.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the eight queens problem efficiently, you  are looking for an efficient way to represent a partial solution.

If we number ranks and files `0` to `7`, and work progressively through the ranks, then a vector `rank -> file` does the job.

- The ranks take care of themselves.
- The free files are what remains of `(set (range 8))`.
- The free rising diagonals are what remains of `(set (range 15))`.
- The free falling diagonals are what remains of `(set (range -7 8))`.

... where, for every square `[i j]`,

- the `rank` is `i`
- the `file` is `j`
- the `rising-diagonal` is `(+ i j)`
- the `falling-diagonal` is `(- i j)`

You could, as [@WolfeFan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37120241/1562315) suggests, use bit-sets to store the free or occupied slots. But the storage concerned is negligible in either representation. And which representation is faster, I wouldn't care to guess.